# Error conexion a base de datos Java, Driver jdbc MySql

Tags: java, jdbc

El error consiste en que al ejecutar el programa no se reconoce el driver, lanzando el error: *`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/comercializadora`*

public class conexion {

```
private static Connection conexion;
private static Statement sentencia;
private static ResultSet resultado;
private static int filas;

private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comercializadora";
private static String usuario = "root";
private static String clave = "";

public static Connection getConection() {
    setConexion(null);
    try {
        setConexion(DriverManager.getConnection(getUrl(), getUsuario(), getClave()));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos \n " + e);
    }

    return getConexion();
}

public static void disconect() throws SQLException {
    getConection().close();
}

public static String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public static void setUrl(String aUrl) {
    url = aUrl;
}

public static String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public static void setUsuario(String aUsuario) {
    usuario = aUsuario;
}

public static String getClave() {
    return clave;
}

public static void setClave(String aClave) {
    clave = aClave;
}

public static Connection getConexion() {
    return conexion;
}

public static void setConexion(Connection aConexion) {
    conexion = aConexion;
}

public static Statement getSentencia() {
    return sentencia;
}

public static void setSentencia(Statement aSentencia) {
    sentencia = aSentencia;
}

public static ResultSet getResultado() {
    return resultado;
}

public static void setResultado(ResultSet aResultado) {
    resultado = aResultado;
}

public static int getFilas() {
    return filas;
}

public static void setFilas(int aFilas) {
    filas = aFilas;
}
```

Comment: Te hace falta el Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); para cargar el driver del conector para java y debes tener la libreria jar para cargarla y poder ejecutar las sentencias sql

Comment: @AndyC `Class.forName` no es necesario desde JDBC 4 ([ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33391649/5587982)). Todo parece indicar que lo que no tiene es el driver JDBC o no lo tiene en el lugar correcto. En cualquier caso, David, si tienes una versión antigua de JDBC conviene que instales la más reciente y no necesitarás `Class.forName`

Comment: Generalmente uso jndi pero es bueno saber el punto que mencionaste. Gracias por la corrección, estaba un poco desactualizado en el asunto del driver.

Comment: Como puedo actualizar el JDBC? 
Lo tengo dentro de las bibliotecas de archivos y aun asi no se conecta a el, tengo la version 5.1